# View disappear after setting zIndex to component

Tags: react-native, flexbox, z-index

I do have this layout, everything worked fine until I added zIndex to a scrollView, the header disappear, tried to give it a bigger zIndex than component didn't work, how I am suppose to make this scrollView on top of the image

navBar

```
renderNavBar() {
  return (
    <Header
      backgroundColor={'rgba(0,0,0, 0.3)'}
      statusBarProps={{ barStyle: 'light-content' }}
      leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#FFF' }}
      centerComponent={{ text: 'ChordHawk', style: { color: '#fff' } }}
      outerContainerStyles={{ minHeight: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0, paddingTop: 25, zIndex: 100000}}
    />
  );
}
```

Content

```
renderContent() {
  return (
<View style={{borderRadius: 20, backgroundColor: '#eee'}}>
<Text style={{fontSize: 16, padding: 50}}>Ingeniis e quibusdam, et irure elit hic fabulas in enim litteris coniunctione se
in export nostrud despicationes, ab est eram constias sed mandaremus labore
possumus nam elit doctrina ea despicationes do eu quo dolor occaecat. E constias
ea aliquip.</Text>
</View>
  );
}
```

Main View (this is a third party library)

```
render() {
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ReactNativeParallaxHeader
          headerMinHeight={70}
          headerMaxHeight={500}
          extraScrollHeight={0}
          backgroundImage={viewImages.background}
          backgroundImageScale={1.0}
          navbarColor={'#168eea'}
          renderNavBar={this.renderNavBar}
          renderContent={this.renderContent}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I tweaked the source files like so:

```
  scrollView: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    position: 'relative',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    marginTop: -50,
    zIndex: 1000
  },
```

My goal is to make those rounded corners on top of the image background, the issue now is that that scroll view comes on top of everything else, can someone please assist

Comment: I would like to help but you code is quite unclear like this. If it is not too much trouble, could you use this: https://snack.expo.io/ to make your question/problem more readable?

Comment: or https://appetize.io/